# Code repetition when working with structures

Tags: c, data-structures, repeat

I am writing an app in C which takes responses from server, parses them and stores them in memory to do something later with that data. Server protocol is based on simple commands which looks like `<Name of the command>#<arg1>#<arg2>...<argn>#%`.

I decided to store those commands in my program the following way. I have a base structure message, which looks like this:

```
struct message
{
   enum message_type type;
   void *msg;
};
```

Enum looks like this:

```
enum message_type
{
   MSG1,
   MSG2,
   ...
   MSGN
};
```

And the specific messages:

```
struct specific_message
{
   int arg1;
   char *arg2;
   ...
   type argn;
};
```

To do some operations with these messages I have huge switch in functions, like:

```
struct message *create_message(enum message_type type)
{
  struct message *res;

  res = malloc(sizeof(*res));

  res->type = type;
  switch(type)
  {
     case MSG1: res->msg = create_msg1(); break;
     ...
     case MSGN: res->msg = create_msgn(); break;
     default: fprintf(stderr, "Unknown msg\n"); free(res); return NULL;
  }

  return res; 
}
```

And specific ones look almost the same(for example if the field is a pointer it is initialized with NULL, if int with -1 etc...)

At first i done it myself by hand, but after writing several such functions i decided to write a script, which gets structs from header and generates such functions(initialization of fields in specific messages, destroying specific messages, copying, etc...).

It works fine, but the size of the implementation file becames very big(it is around 1000 lines now, and it is just the creation, copying and destruction). And I can't write those via a macro(well at least i don't know how), because macros don't know anything about the layout of the structure. So the whole file becomes repetitive.

I thought about different approaches, for example to have just the base message structure which would contain command type, number of arguments and array of char*, which would contain those arguments in string form. But then I need to add all this logic for retrieving the arguments I need from this array and casting it to the type I need. So I thought it wouldn't scale.

Is there another approach I could use?

Comment: Your `message` is asking to be a `union` of all the possible messages. Won't eliminate the need for the `switch/case`, but will make the data more organized.  How "similar" specific messages are?

Comment: @EugeneSh. For now the only types that specific messages use is char* and int. But I'll say they are different by meaning. Almost every messages have it's own meaning of arguments.

Comment: @Udalny, Perhaps an array of create functions, and then call `res->msg = create[type]()`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, well it would help to get rid of switch, but I'll still need to write or generate all those create() functions. I was looking for maybe some kind of structure reorganization or pattern to simplify this.

Comment: @Udalny Within `struct message`, add members like `struct message *(create)(void)`.  Initilaize them when defined, call as needed.  As time goes on, you will re-invent C++.